# How does temperature affect the movement of electrons?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrons, temperature

Since temperature is a measure of the kinetic energy of the particles, does that mean as we increase temperature we increase the speed on electrons? or there's a different theory regarding electrons?

Comment: Are you asking about electrons that are free, or are you wondering about bound electrons, that is electrons that are part of atoms and molecules?

Comment: @Countto10 both :)

Comment: There is a relationship between temperature and the average kinetic energy of the particles, but that's different from defining temperature to be proportional to the kinetic energy of particles. One should really think of that relationship as a manifestation of the equipartition theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, temperature is not a measure of the kinetic energy of the molecules, but a measure of the "average" kinetic energy of the molecules. In the case of a bounded electron, thermal energy can induce vibrations in the atom. This may rupture bonds and may cause the emission of the electron. So, the electron will try to get out of that bond if you supply thermal energy. This is what that happens in the [thermal generation of electron-hole pairs in semiconductors](https://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter2/ch2_8.htm).

For a free electron, it has got kinetic energy only (which is a continuous spectrum). Increased thermal agitation will of course increase the kinetic energy of the electrons. However, the thermal motion is not directional, but random. So, the net velocity of the molecules along any direction will be zero. But, there exists an average thermal velocity as governed by the [equipartition theorem](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/eqpar.html), which states that in three dimensions, the energy of a free particle is given by

$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{3}{2}k_BT$$

where, $v$- average velocity of the electron at a particular temperature $T$, $m$ is the rest mass of the particle and $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant.The average thermal velocity is hence,

$$v=\sqrt{\frac{3k_BT}{m}}$$

For a free electron, this value at room temperature ($300K$) is about $1.17\times 10^5m/s$, which is a very large value. Now, suppose we are dealing with free electrons in a conductor under a potential difference $V$. Then, the net velocity of the electron will be due to thermal energy (random and is of the order of $10^5m/s$) and electrical energy (drift velocity and is too slow of the order of $1m/hr$). So the thermal velocity dominates the drift velocity. However, it is the drift velocity that contributes mainly to electrical conduction.

However, the application of equipartition theorem and being a follower of kinetic energy is valid as far as you stick with the assumptions favouring the electrons obeying [Boltzmann statistics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/disfcn.html). AT electron energies less than $k_BT$, one should take care that the Boltzmann statistics no longer plays good and we need to use [Fermi-Dirac statistics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/disfd.html).